# Compactly supported geometric representatives for Seiberg-Witten invariant

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, gauge-theory

> The question is introduced at the end of the second paragraph.
> Readers familiar with Seiberg-Witten theory may well skip the first paragraph.
> The first paragraph is meant to set up some notation which is mostly standard, I've written it because I suspect there may be an hidden error in the second part which maybe stems from some detail in the first.

### Classical Seiberg-Witten invariant

Let $X$ be a smooth, closed oriented 4-manifold equipped with a $spin^c$ structure $\mathfrak{s}$ and $b^+(X)>1$. Set $d := \frac 1 4 (c_1(\mathfrak{s})^2 - 2\chi(X) - 3\sigma(X))$.

In order to define Seiberg-Witten invariants of $(X,\mathfrak{s})$, one considers the
the universal $U(1)$-bundle $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X)$ over the irreducible configurations modulo gauge: (the $spin^c$ structure is fixed so I will drop it from the notation.)

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathcal{G}/\mathcal{G_0}@>>>  \mathcal{C}^*(X)/\mathcal{G_0}(X) @>>> \mathcal{C}^*(X)/\mathcal{G}(X)\\
    @VV\sim V  @|        @|\\
    U(1) @>>> \tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X) @>>> \mathcal{B}^*(X)
\end{CD}
Where $\mathcal{G}(X)= Maps(X,U(1)) $ is the gauge group, $\mathcal{C}^*(X)$ is the space of  *irreducible* configurations and
$\mathcal{G}_0(X) \subset \mathcal{G}$ is the gauge group based at $x_0\in X$, i.e. $u\in \mathcal{G}(X)$ s.t. $u(x_0) = 1$. $\mathcal{B}^*(X)$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X)$ are defined by the above diagram.

Let $\mu $ denote  the first Chern class of $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X)\to \mathcal{B}^*(X)$.
Then we can consider a geometric representative $Y\subset \mathcal{B^*}(X)$ for $\mu^{d/2}\in H^d(\mathcal{B}^*(X))$.  $D$ is a codimension 2 submanifold Poincarè dual to $\mu^{d/2}$, i.e. for any finite dimensional, compact, oriented and smooth submanifold  $M \subset \mathcal{B}^*(X)$, we have that $[D\cap M]$ is Poincarè dual to $\mu^{d/2}$.
Then one defines
$$SW(X, \mathfrak{s}) = \# (D\cap \mathcal{M}_\eta(X,\mathfrak{s}))$$
as the intersection number between $D$ and $\mathcal{M}_\eta(X,\mathfrak{s})$, the moduli space of monopoles perturbed by $\eta$ (so that $\mathcal{M}_\eta$ is smooth, finite dimensional submanifold of $\mathcal{B}^*$). Here I tacitly  assumed that an orientation for $\mathcal{M}_\eta$ was choosen.

### Compactly supported geometric representatives of $\mu^d$

Now let $K\subset X$ be a compact set (EDIT: submanifold) with *non-empty interior*. The restriction map induces a partial function $$r:\mathcal{B}^*(X)\dashrightarrow \mathcal{B}^*(K)$$
this is not defined over all of $\mathcal{B}^*(X)$ because there might be  irreducible configurations $(A,\phi)\in \mathcal{C}(X)$ such that $(A|_K, \phi|_K)\in \mathcal{C}(K)$ is reducible. However, thanks to unique continuation, this does not happen for monopoles, so that $\mathcal{M}_\eta^*(X)\subset \mathrm{dom}(r)$, and  restriction induces a map
$r: \mathcal{M}_\eta^*(X)\to \mathcal{M}_\eta^*(K)$.

Thus we have the diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
      & &   \tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X)|_{\mathrm{dom}(r)} @>>\overline{r}>  \tilde{\mathcal{B}}(K)\\
     &  @VVV        @VVV\\
    \mathcal{M}_\eta(X) @>>i> \mathrm{dom}(r) @>>r> \mathcal{B}^*(K)
\end{CD}
where $\overline{r}$ is $\mathbb{S}^1$ equivariant, and therefore $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X)|_{\mathrm{dom}(r)} = r^* \tilde{\mathcal{B}}(K)$ and
$$SW(X) = \langle \mu(X)^{d/2},[\mathcal{M}_\eta(X)]\rangle = \langle r^*\mu(K)^{d/2}, [\mathcal{M}_\eta(X)]\rangle = \langle \mu(K)^{d/2}, [r(\mathcal{M}_\eta(X))]\rangle = \#(D_K\cap r (\mathcal{M}_\eta(X)) )$$
Where $D_K\subset \mathcal{B}^*(K)$ is a geometric representative of $\mu^{d/2}(K)$ (orientations of $\mathcal{M}$ and $spin^c$ structures are ommitted).

*I think that $D_K$ is what some authors mean whey they say compactly supported geometric representative but unfortunately I could not find a formal statement for the definition. I would be happy if experts could confirm that this definition is correct.*

**Q1:** is the above definition sound? In particular is it true that we can compute the SW invariant using any geometric representative $D_K$?

**Q2:** How are compactly supported representatives used usually? Why are they useful? I imagine that one can choose $D_K$ so that an $\eta$-monopole in $D_K$ satisfies some inequality on $K$ (maybe some concentration inequality like $\frac{\int_{X}|\phi|^2}{\int_{K}|\phi|^2}< \varepsilon$ for a fixed $\varepsilon$) is this correct?

**Q3** We know that $\mathcal{B}^*(X)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}P^\infty \times K(H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}),1)$, does the universal  $U(1)$-bundle $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}(X)$ correspond to the $U(1)$-bundle  induced by the generator  of $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^\infty,\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: I don't know how you're computing the invariant (via restriction) since $\partial K$ is nonempty.

Comment: @ChrisGerig thank you for your comment.  Maybe it's better to assume $K$  to be a compact codimension 0 submanifold with boundary. Then $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}^*(K)\to \mathcal{B}^*(K)$ is a still a  line bundle over an Hilbert manifold regardless $\partial K$, the restriction $\mathcal{M}_\eta(X)\to \mathcal{B}^*(K)$ is smooth, hence there is a section $s$, of $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}(K)$  such that $s\circ r|_{\mathcal{M}(X)}$ is transverse to the zero section. If this is correct then we should be able to count points as usual.

Comment: I was already assuming $K$ to be a 4-submanifold, but your inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ doesn't make sense to me over $K$ due to the presence of boundary.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I'm a bit confused now, are you questioning that $\mathcal{B}^*(K)$ is an Hilbert space or the  pairing $\langle \mu^{d/2}(K), [r\mathcal{M}_\eta(X)]\rangle$ (or something else)?
In the former case there shouldn't be any problem (the theory for $X^4$ with boundary  is developed in Kronheimer&Mrowka's book section 9 and 24), and in the latter we can think of it as   pulling the bundle back over the moduli space $\mathcal{M}_\eta(X)$ which is closed and has all the possible good properties.  I'm probably missing something, could you elaborate a little bit?